# How to check whether ResultSet returned a result?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, resultset

I am new to javaEE and trying to use database. I am simply checking the username and password from the database. Here is the code:

```
protected void CheckUser(String username, String password)
{

    try {
        connect();
        PreparedStatement checkDB = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM Users where username = ? AND password = ?");
        checkDB.setString(1,username);
        checkDB.setString(2,password);
        ResultSet rs =null;
        rs=(ResultSet) checkDB.executeQuery();
        if(rs !=null)
        {
            System.out.println("heheheh");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("awwwwww");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("cannot connect");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thşs code always enters if block even though login info is incorrect. What can i do about it?

Thanks

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: @SLaks you are right but i am just beginning i will do it later

Comment: Based from your last question, since this is a web application, you should use a logger instead of `System.out.println` statements.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes you are right i am doing it just for debugging purposes

Comment: Since we are suggesting improvements, I have a few to add:
- Why are you casting `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` is not necessary
- Is not necessary to initialize `Resultset rs = null` with `ResultSet rs;` is enough
- You should avoid catching ´Exception´ here you should probably catch a `SQLException`

Comment: feel free to make suggestions

Comment: I pressed Enter by mistake, fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`executeQuery()` will always return a `ResultSet` instance.

You want to check whether it has any rows, by calling `next()` and checking whether it returns false.

Also, you need to close the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

The `ResultSet` object will not be `null`, even if no rows are returned.  Use the [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) method on the `ResultSet`, which will return `false` on the first call if there are no rows.

Additionally, you should close the `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement` once you're done with them.